# Как узнать номер строки по слову?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Допустим есть файл

> "test.txt"

И там есть слово

> "word"

На не извесной строке. Как узнать на какой оно строке?
(За ответ буду очень благодарен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно читать файл построчно с использованием функции [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), которая принимает последовательность и номер, с которого начинать подсчет (в данном случае 1, по умолчанию - 0) в качестве аргументов и возвращает на каждом шаге индекс элемента и значение элемента (строка из файла). Для проверки наличия слова в строке пишем `if 'word' in line:`

```
with open('test.txt') as text_file:
    for num, line in enumerate(text_file, 1):
        if 'word' in line:
            print(num)
```